# Dramatiq ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dramatiq

I have project with next structure:

app.py

src

__ check_health.py

__ health_checker.py

venv

---

**health_checker.py**

```
import requests


def health_checker():
    host = 'http://172.22.19.244:49250/api/v1/health'
    response = requests.get(host).json()
    print(response)
```

**check_health.py**

```
from src.health_cheker import health_checker
import dramatiq

@dramatic.actor
def check_health():
    health_checker()
```

**app.py**

```
from src.check_health import check_health


if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_health.send()
```

When I try to start dramatiq with

```
dramatiq check_health
```

dramatiq raise error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

what I do wrong?

Comment: do you have __init__ file in src ?

Comment: Do you have a typo: from src.health_**cheker** import health_checker